# Web Api High Response Latency (Asp.net, Azure)

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

After deploying my Web Api to Azure, I noticed that I have a very high response latency. I stopwatched a method that awaits a Http request to a controller that just returns a "Hello" string. The times I measure are also not consistent, but most of the time I get something around 0.9 seconds. The problem is, that my database queries take forever, even the least fancy ones take something around two seconds (and when my UI updates multiple elements, it takes up to 4 seconds until the whole thing is loaded).

I have really no idea where to start diagnosing this issue, so any help (even the most basic) would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, I used Database.EnsureCreated() on every service request, since it was called in the constructor of the DbContext I inject on Startup. Seems pretty unefficient. Whoopsie!